# Extending helper functions in Lithium

Tags: php, lithium

I want to use [this code](https://gist.github.com/Hakaze/5039884) to extend the form helper class, can someone explain where I need to save the code and how to make sure it gets included when I create my forms.

Currently I've saved it to `extensions/helper/Forms.php` and then calling it with

`<?php
use app\extensions\helper\Form; 
?>`

inside my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've placed and named the file correctly. But helpers are used inside templates.

```
<p>Here is a <?= $this->html->link('link', 'http://li3.me') ?> you'll all enjoy.</p>
```

See the manual for more info http://li3.me/docs/manual/views/helpers.md